# Execute instance method synchronously inside a model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I have two models (let say model1 and model2) and both have hasmany-belongs to relationship.
model2 have the foreign key for model1.

I want to access the model1 data inside the model2 instance method.

My Code for model2 is something like this

```js
module.exports = {
    attributes     : {
        name         : {
            type       : 'url',
            required   : true,
            unique     : true
        },
        model1       : {
            model      : 'Model1',
        },
        model1Data   : function() {
            var data = [];
            sails.models.model1.findOne(
                {'id':this.model1}
            ).done(function(err, model1) {
                data.push(model1);
            });
            return data;
        }
    },
};
```

Here the when I call model1.model1Data(), it return an empty array, as the functions are executed asynchronously.

So how do I get the data of the model1 ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Basically, What do you want to do?

Comment: Welcome to node.js, where you are forced to create callback spaghetti code :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `return data`. Add a callback argument to the `model2.model1Data()` function.

```
// ...
model1Data   : function(cb) {
  var data = [];
    sails.models.model1.findOne(
      {'id':this.model1}
      ).done(function(err, model1) {
         data.push(model1);
         cb(err, data)
    });
    // return data;
}
// ...
```

Then you can call `model2.model1Data()` like this:

```
sails.model2.model1Data(function(err, data) {
  if (err) return;

  // process the data here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the async module could be used for this:

```
var async = require('async');
//
async.series{[

    //this will always run first
    function(callback) {
        //do your model1 logic
        callback();
    },

    //this will always run second
    function(callback) {
        //do your model2 logic, which will enable you to find your model1Data
        callback();
    }
]};
```